# Two OnClickListeners, two buttons. (savedpreferences)

Tags: java, android

I have two edittext blocks + two buttons (who work with savedpreferences), I can't seem to figure out how to use a onclicklistener on both? I now have two buttons who need to something else on a onclicklistener. How do I alter the code for this to work?

I'm really new to android.

**Maincode**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    EditText editText;
    EditText editText1;
    Button button;
    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    loadSavedPreferences();
    loadSavedPreferences1();
}

        private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String name = sharedPreferences.getString("storedName", "YourName");
    editText.setText(name);
}

private void loadSavedPreferences1() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String onderwerp = sharedPreferences.getString("storedOnderwerp", "YourOnderwerp");
    editText1.setText(onderwerp);
}

private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

private void savePreferences1(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor1 = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor1.putString(key, value);
    editor1.commit();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    savePreferences("storedName", editText.getText().toString());

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "Meldingtekst is aangepast.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    savePreferences1("storedOnderwerp", editText1.getText().toString());

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "Meldingonderwerp is aangepast.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: first you should try to understand the concept of Interfaces. If you will understand it then you never confuse in such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(v==button)
    {
        savePreferences("storedName", editText.getText().toString());    
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Meldingtekst is aangepast.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    else if(v==button1)    
    {    
        savePreferences1("storedOnderwerp", editText1.getText().toString());    
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Meldingonderwerp is aangepast.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked! I'll give it the right answer symbol when I am allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click   

                Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class);

                 startActivity(activityChangeIntent);


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override onClick() method only once. Write like this :

```
@Override
```

public void onClick(View v) {

```
if(v == button)
{
savePreferences("storedName", editText.getText().toString());

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
        "Meldingtekst is aangepast.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
   else if(v == button1)

   {

   savePreferences1("storedOnderwerp", editText1.getText().toString());

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
        "Meldingonderwerp is aangepast.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this. this is optimized way of handling your button click

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch(v.getId())
{
case R.id.button1:
    savePreferences("storedName", editText.getText().toString());

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "Meldingtekst is aangepast.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
break;
case R.id.button2:
     savePreferences1("storedOnderwerp", editText1.getText().toString());

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "Meldingonderwerp is aangepast.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not to write two onClick(View v) for two buttons, you just have two put this condition inside your onClick(View v):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.button:
 // code for button 1
break;
case R.id.button1:
 // code for button 2
break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its always preferd to create innerclass for clickLister in Android as per Java.

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
         savePreferences("storedName", editText.getText().toString());

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "Meldingtekst is aangepast.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
       });

     button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
         savePreferences("storedName", editText.getText().toString());

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "Meldingtekst is aangepast.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand concept of Interfaces to understand what you should do. This link you can check it will help you to understand how you can use onClickListner.

http://martin.cubeactive.com/android-onclicklitener-tutorial/

Comment: :) yup basics are very useful.